# Load dynamic view in laravel 5.5 with ajax

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I want to load left side menu dynamically in laravel. When I pass a generated string to view and return then it not works. But the same string when I paste and load it loads.This Menu loads based on roles.

Controller Code:
`$str = GenerateLeftMenu::getLeftMenu();
return view('layouts.partial.left_menu')->with('check',$str)->render();`
Ajax Code:

```
$( window ).on( "load", 
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url : "/getLeftMenu",
            dataType: "html",
            success : function(response) {
                $( "#side-menu" ).load(response);
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function() {
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: what errors do you have?

Comment: String loads but string not render. such as <li><a href = "{{route("home") }}"><i class = "fa fa-briefcase"></i> but it not converted to url

Comment: why are you doing 2 ajax calls?

Comment: why do you need the ajax if you are triggering the ajax at page load?

Comment: No, I don't need ajax call. I have to load the left menus based on roles. Thats it.

Comment: I have tried  to load that in many ways.

Comment: how do you check if a user has a specific role?

Comment: Role is assigned to user when a user registered. And when login I get fron session or dirrect from db.

Comment: @Md.ShamsImran please see my answer.. hope it will heps you

Comment: try using .html instead since you already have the value ready

Answer (score 0):

According to your question it must work.. when i used to do these things i like to do in that way without render. You can try once:-

```
$str = GenerateLeftMenu::getLeftMenu(); // make sure $str having data
$check = $str;
return view('layouts.partial.left_menu')->with(compact('check'));
```

and in success function like this:-

```
success : function(response) {
            $( "#side-menu" ).html(response); //replace load to html
            console.log(response);
        },
```

Hope it helps!